# Multiple regression does not return binary results

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I am trying to do a multiple regression for a model using glm() regression, predict() and prediction(). I need to predict binary results, as my target variable is binary, but I am not getting those kind of results, and I don't know what am I doing worng. This is my code:

```
   model<-glm(formula = NextAccident ~ ., family = binomial, data = 
   train.set)
   head(model)
   pr.crash <- predict(model, newdata = train.set, type = 'response')
   head(pr.crash)
   pred <- prediction(pr.crash, train.set$NextAccident)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you predict with glm() using type = “response”, what you obtain is the predicted probability  that your binary outcome variable takes the value 1 (presuming you coded this variable as a binary variable which takes on either the value 0 or the value 1).

The training set helps you identify a sensible glm model for your data. You can fit the same model to your test data set and produce predicted probabilities as you have done for the training set. Next, use these predicted probabilities to decide whether the model would have classified an observation from the test data set as a 1 (if predicted probability is greater than or equal to a threshold) or 0 (if predicted probability is less than the same threshold).  The threshold can be something like 0.5 or other sensible value for your problem. Do the same for each observation in your test data set to determine how good the model is at classifying new data as 0 or 1. (Of course, you can use the same principle to determine how good the model is at classifying the obsevations in the training data set.) The whole idea is that you need to dichotomize the predicted probability for each observation using a sensible threshold.

Comment: What you propose to use here, accuracy, is an improper score rule. Better to use some proper score rule